# Can I use an activity to initialize some objects then finish?

Tags: android, android-activity

If I initialize some static objects in an activity and then call `finish()`, do those objects still exist elsewhere in the application? Like say I want to access them later on in a service.

If not, are there any other solutions where I could initialize some static objects one time that other classes will have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing that is possible. But for the static objects to continue to exist, there should be at least one Activity/Service in the application to be running. What I normally do for such variables is to create a class to hold static methods and variables. Something like this:

```
public class Utils
{
    public static String s;
    public static int i;

    public static initStatics()
    {
        s = "";
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This you can call from your other Activity/Service like this:

```
public class CustomService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        Utils.initStatics();
    }
}
```

So, these variables will be available as long as your app is running. Hope that helped. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For things of that nature you can use static member variables on the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object. You will have to clean up manually (since `onDestroy` is never called), and you will need to make sure there is at least one Activity/Service in the application running to prevent the app's process from being destroyed by the OS.